# Limitations of Amazon Machine Image (AMI)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

As Amazon Web Services [mentions](https://aws.amazon.com/amis),

> An Amazon Machine Image (AMI) is a special type of pre-configured
>   operating system and virtual application software which is used to
>   create a virtual machine within the Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud
>   (EC2). It serves as the basic unit of deployment for services
>   delivered using EC2.

So AMI is a kind of virtual machine which we can use as a server to host our applications. So my questions are,

1. What are the limitations in AMI with compared to a normal server?
2. Can we install any software in the AMI?

Answer (score 4):

AMI is not any server running; it is like a "backup of your server" on hard disk. Using this back-up you can bring up running servers instantly.

Concept of Imaging server is used in all IT companies. Suppose an IT companies give Windows 7 to new joinees with few pre-installed software. So, instead of configuring the laptop for every joinee; they will create an image and will just dump that image on new laptop and give it to new joinee.

Same Image when created on Amazon Web services is called as AMI. AMI is just an image of any server... It is something like you firstly make your machine ready ( with any operating system and all the softwares you need on them ) and then create an image out of it which is called as AMI.

To answer your questions; 
1. Not sure what limitations you are talking about; but as such there is no limitation.
2. Yes you can install any software. To make things clear; you can even install a virus on the server ; and then create an AMI.